# How to dynamically import only one SCSS file based on language selection in a Next.js application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm working on a Next.js application where I need to dynamically import an SCSS file based on the selected language. Currently, my RootLayout component imports both the ltr.scss and rtl.scss files regardless of the selected language:

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

async function RootLayout({ children, params: { lang } }) {

  if(lang === "en"){
    dynamic(() => import(`../../../Styles/direction/ltr.scss`)); 
  }else{
    dynamic(() => import(`../../../Styles/direction/rtl.scss`));
  }

  // ...
}
```

What I want to do is import only the relevant SCSS file based on the selected language, i.e., import ltr.scss when the language is set to "en" and rtl.scss when the language is set to "ar".

How can I modify my code to achieve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!.

i am using next js 13.4.1 version and app directory inside that.